# Update =NOW() -- before -- generating email with hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

Have a hyperlink in B7 generating email, which uses E7 with =NOW() that goes as part of email's subject line. Using below code updates only after generating email, need before:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b7")) Is Nothing Then 'before email is generated to update =NOW in E7
Application.Calculate
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event - maybe you can use that

Comment: @Ike - thanks, aware, only matter of how

Comment: How did you create the Hyperlink? Via `HYPERLINK`-Formula or as via context menu > insert link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using the `HYPERLINK`-function you can put `NOW` in the subject part:

`=HYPERLINK("mailto:xx@XXX.com?subject=Report FROM "  & TEXT(NOW(),"dd.MM.YYYY hh:nn"),"send mail")`

Comment: Thanks @ike, I was using:  =HYPERLINK("mailto:" &D6 & "?subject="& D7 & " - " & TEXT(E7,"MM.DD.YYYY - Hh:Mm:Ss") &"&body=" & D8,"Email"). Now replaced reference to a separate cell E7 with NOW() right in the formula.  Hopefully that will always give the updated current time, once it's in the email subject line.